# How can I create a connection between two virtual machines?

Tags: virtualization

I've virtual Box installed with backtrack and XP SP2 Virtual machines, on a Windows 7 host machine. How can I create a connection between them?

Comment: Is your question about forming a network connection between two virtual machines, or is it about pen testing?

Comment: Hi it's about forming connection between virtual Machine >> Please Answer This , Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You just need to have both VMs running at the same time on the host system and configure the network correctly on the two VMs, then they should be able to "see" each other. From there you start your learning.

To test if it works you will just need to ping one of them from the other.

Here's a Virtualbox networking tutorial - http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's something with your networking configuration for the virtual machines. Please take a look [here](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html).
The default option is NAT, if you're having problems you might want to switch to bridged mode.